# JRE not running correctly on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, jre

An application called [DosBox Game Launcher](http://members.quicknet.nl/blankendaalr/dbgl/) (DBGL) requires JRE in order to run successfully. I had it installed and running on my old Windows 7 32-bit machine without any problems. Today I got my new PC with Windows 64-bit, and I cannot get it running anymore.

If I install the latest JRE 32-bit version to the `\Program Files (x86)` folder DBGL says it needs the latest JRE version in order to run and doesn't start. If I install the latest JRE 64-bit version to the `\Program Files` folder I do not get an error message anymore but the application doesn't start either. Clicking it has literally no effect.

Right now I have both JRE versions running parallely, and I get the same result I have when only the 64-bit version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the 32-bit Java runtime to your [PATH](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) instead of the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution worked:

1. Uninstall all JREs from your computer
2. Open an administrator Command Prompt and type the following:

   ```
   bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx Alwaysoff
   ```

   You will see the message:

   ```
   The operation completed successfully.
   ```
3. Reinstall Java for 64-bit